# Create dates array in groovy

Tags: arrays, date, groovy, soapui

I am trying to create array in groovy where multiple dates can be stored.
e.g : I am checking availability in various dates and if found available, I want to add it to my array.
So basically I have while loop with a variable which decides how many times the loop iterate. Array length should be equal to the number of time loop iterate.

The expected result should look like :

`"2019/12/02","2019/12/03","2019/12/04"`

**My Code** :

```
def SeriesDaysNumber = context.expand('${#Project#SeriesDaysNumber}')
def dates = new String[SeriesDaysNumber]

while(isAvailable == false) 
{   
    log.info "Inside While loop"
    for (i = 0; i < SeriesDaysNumber.toInteger(); i++)      
    { 
     // some DB query to check availability 

    if(res[0].toString() == '0')        
    {
            isAvailable = true
            seriesEndDate2 = "${SeriesEndDate1.format(outputDateFormatSeries)}"
            context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('SeriesEndDate', seriesEndDate2)
            // this date is available so add it to array, here i use zero index but i want it dynamically.
            dates[i] = seriesEndDate2.toString()
            log.info "dates : " + dates
    use(TimeCategory)
    {
    // here i am incrementing the date 
    }
    }
    }
}
```

**Actual Result**

`Mon Dec 02 15:24:56 IST 2019:INFO:dates : [2019/12/02, 2019/12/05, 2019/12/08, 2019/12/11, 2019/12/14, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`

Comment: `dates[0]` not `dates[i]`?

Comment: So, those dates are not available... And according to your logic they should be null. BTW., what is the question?

Comment: SeriesDaysNumber value is 5 in this example. So why there are so much null in the array. And those dates I want it in above-mentioned format.

Comment: ok able to resolve this null issue. def dates = new String[SeriesDaysNumber.toInteger()]

now the formating is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are 4 things I need to do to achieve the expected result :**

1. `dates[i]` instead of `dates[0]`
   To store all dates in an array.
2. `def dates = new String[SeriesDaysNumber.toInteger()]`
   To resolve the null issue.
3. `dates[i] = "\""+seriesEndDate2.toString()+"\""`
   To put dates into double quotes.
4. `log.info "dates : " + dates.join(", ")` To remove square brackets from array.